# Java Regex match UTF-8 String (Without Copy)

Tags: java, regex, performance, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm loading large UTF-8 text from a SocketChannel, and need to extract some values. Pattern matching with `java.util.regex` is great for this, but decoding to Java's UTF-16 with `CharBuffer cb = UTF_8.decode(buffer);` copies this buffer, using double the space.

Is there a way to create a CharBuffer 'view' in UTF-8, or otherwise pattern match with a charset?

Comment: does your regex include unicode? if not you may get away with treating test as ASCII and redecode extracted fragments as UTF-8 later

Comment: Yes, the regex is all ascii. Can you give an example? Lets say ByteBuffer b is UTF-8 "hello alexey", and the Pattern is Pattern.compile("hello (?<person>.*)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create lightweight `CharSequence` wrapping `ByteBuffer` which does simple byte to char conversion without proper UTF8 handling.

As long as your regex is Latin1 characters only, it would work event on "naively" converted string.

Only ranges matched by reg ex needs to be properly decodec from UTF8.

Below in code illustrating this approach.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;


public class RegExSnippet {

    private static Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF8");

    @Test
    public void testByteBufferRegEx() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // this UTF8 byte encoding of test string
        byte[] bytes = ("lkfmd;wmf;qmfqv amwfqwmf;c "
        + "<tag>This is some non ASCII text 'кирилицеский текст'</tag>"
        + "kjnfdlwncdlka-lksnflanvf ").getBytes(UTF8);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

        ByteSeqWrapper bsw = new ByteSeqWrapper(bb);

        // pattern should contain only LATIN1 characters
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<tag>(.*)</tag>").matcher(bsw);

        Assert.assertTrue(m.find());

        String body = m.group(1);

        // extracted part is properly decoded as UTF8
        Assert.assertEquals("This is some non ASCII text 'кирилицеский текст'", body);
    }

    public static class ByteSeqWrapper implements CharSequence {

        final ByteBuffer buffer;

        public ByteSeqWrapper(ByteBuffer buf) {
            this.buffer = buf;
        }

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return buffer.remaining();
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return (char) (0xFF & buffer.get(index));
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            ByteBuffer bb = buffer.duplicate();
            bb.position(bb.position() + start);
            bb.limit(bb.position() + (end - start));
            return new ByteSeqWrapper(bb);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // a little hack to apply proper encoding
            // to a parts extracted by matcher
            CharBuffer cb = UTF8.decode(buffer);
            return cb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, this is awesome! SO much better to be able to use Regex than manually seeking byte by byte. Thanks!